# Coping the text of gridview cell in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to copy the text of 3rd cell of 4th row of a gridview, in asp.net.

And I am not able to do that...

Can someone help in solving it, with a code...

Comment: On the client or server side? Could you also show the ASPX markup you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
String text = this.gridView.Rows[3].Cells[2].Text;
```